# IFilter or SDK for many file types?

Tags: .net, sdk, adobe, ms-office, ifilter

Does anybody know of an API/SDK or IFilter in .NET that can read the subject ('title' metadata) and text from the following files:

.PDF
.DOC
.XLS
.PPT
.CSV
.TXT
.DOCX
.XLS
.PPTX
+ the OpenOffice and Open Document standards.

Open source would be awesome... but commercial is OK too.

I can't find anything anywhere!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to find a single IFilter that will be able to access the contents of all of those types. Typically, an IFilter will be for a specific technology.

For example, Adobe [have one for PDFs](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=2611), Microsoft provide one for Office that can do Word, Excel, Powerpoint, CSV (that I believe comes pre-installed with Windows).

Comment: Another alternative for PDF text indexing is FoxIt Software. http://www.foxitsoftware.com I've found their PDF IFilter much more reliable than Adobe's.

Comment: Although it's not an IFilter, I have gone with Aspose.NET for reading files. I suppose one could make an IFilter wrapper for Aspose.NET.