# Library to read MANY document-file formats?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing an ASP.NET in which I have a "file upload" control. So, User may upload files of any format like .doc, .pdf, .docx, .txt, .rtf, .ppt, .odt etc.

The program must be able read data from any file of these formats. I dont want to use different third party libraries for each of these file formats. I want one common solution to read all these files.

Comment: The file formats listed cover a very broad scope. Consider what is desired to be done with the data -- what does "read" need to do?

Comment: Files other than .txt are stored in their own binary format. It is not possible to read their contents directly without an interpreter. Try opening the above mentioned files in a program like notepad++. The file contents will be incomprehensible! If you do not want to use third party libraries, you are free to implement your own.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IFilter or SDK for many file types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535992/ifilter-or-sdk-for-many-file-types)

Answer (score 0):

You can use File.RreadAllBytes() method of System.IO namespace to read all the bytes of an file into byte array. You can get more information about this method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx)

As you said you are developing Asp.net application. So I think you must be using fileupload control. If yes then you can use FileUpload control's FileBytes property to read all the bytes of an file. More information about FileUpload control can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx)